Why are there two breaker boxes in my home?
I've noticed that our single family home has 2 separate breaker boxes. I've been wondering why 2 is needed for a one story, single family dwelling? Our home used to have a garage that was converted into a bed room, could that be the reason why? One breaker box is directly behind laundry room door and second breaker box is on the inside of the cabinets on the opposite side of the laundry room. In the event that we would want to replace said breaker boxes, could they be combined?

A few reasons to have two or more.  A too small main/first panel plus the need for extra circuits is a prime reason.  Pictures of the two panels will help.

Photos are a must. There are three different possibilities: 2 separate utility services, one panel is a subpanel of the other panel, 2 panels both feeding directly from one meter. A subpanel is normal, the others are not. But how to handle any of them will depend on all the details.

I have a separate subpanel with loads that I decided would be good to use against a generator in a power out event - then I can power the fridges and lights with a low end generator.
